# Terraform EKS configmaps is forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy a `Kubernetes` cluster on `AWS EKS` using `Terraform`, run from a `Gitlab CI` pipeline. My code currently gets a full cluster up and running, except there is a step in which it tries to add the nodes (which are created separately) into the cluster.

When it tries to do this, this is the error I receive:

```
│ Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default" cannot create resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
│ 
│   with module.mastercluster.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/mastercluster/aws_auth.tf line 63, in resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth":
│   63: resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
│
```

`Terraform` I believe is trying to edit the configmap `aws_auth` in the `kube-system` namespace, but for whatever reason, it doesn't have permission to do so?

I have found a different answer from years ago on Stackoverflow, that currently matches with what the documentation has to say about adding a `aws_eks_cluster_auth` data source and adding this to the `kubernetes` provider.

My configuration of this currently looks like this:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "mastercluster" {
    name    = module.mastercluster.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "mastercluster" {
    name    = module.mastercluster.cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
    alias   = "mastercluster"

    host                    = data.aws_eks_cluster.mastercluster.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate  = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.mastercluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
    token                   = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.mastercluster.token

    load_config_file        = false
}
```

The weird thing is, this has worked for me before. I have successfully deployed multiple clusters using this method. This configuration is an almost identical copy to another one I had before, only the names of the clusters are different. I am totally lost as to why this can possibly go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `semver` to lock `hashicorp provider` versions

That's why is so important to use [`semver`](https://semver.org) in `terraform` manifests.

As per [Terraform documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-versioning):

> Terraform providers manage resources by communicating between Terraform and target APIs. Whenever the target APIs change or add functionality, provider maintainers may update and version the provider.
>
> When multiple users or automation tools run the same Terraform configuration, they should all use the same versions of their required providers.

## Use `RBAC` rules for `Kubernetes`

There is a Github issue filed about this: [v2.0.1: Resources cannot be created. Does kubectl reference to kube config properly? · Issue #1127 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/1127) with the same error message as in yours case.

And [one of the comments answers](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/1127#issuecomment-765635852):

> Offhand, this looks related to [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) rules in the cluster (which may have been installed by the helm chart). This command might help diagnose the permissions issues relating to the service account in the error message.
>
> ```
> $ kubectl auth can-i create namespace --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-prod:default
> $ kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-prod:default
> ```
>
> You might be able to compare that list with other users on the cluster:
>
> ```
> kubectl auth can-i --list --namespace=default --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default
> ```
>
> ```
> $ kubectl auth can-i create configmaps
> yes
>
> $ kubectl auth can-i create configmaps --namespace=nginx-ingress --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-prod:default
> no
> ```
>
> And investigate related clusterroles:
>
> ```
> $ kube describe clusterrolebinding system:basic-user
> Name:         system:basic-user
> Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
> Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
> Role:
>   Kind:  ClusterRole
>   Name:  system:basic-user
> Subjects:
>   Kind   Name                  Namespace
>   ----   ----                  ---------
>   Group  system:authenticated
>
>
> $ kubectl describe clusterrole system:basic-user
> Name:         system:basic-user
> Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
> Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
> PolicyRule:
>   Resources                                      Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
>   ---------                                      -----------------  --------------  -----
>   selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io  []                 []              [create]
>   selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                 []              [create]
> ```
>
> My guess is that the chart or Terraform config in question is responsible for creating the service account, and the [cluster] roles and rolebindings, but it might be doing so in the wrong order, or not idempotently (so you get different results on re-install vs the initial install). But we would need to see a configuration that reproduces this error. In my testing of version 2 of the providers on [AKS](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/tree/master/_examples/aks), [EKS](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/tree/master/_examples/eks), [GKE](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/tree/master/_examples/gke), and [minikube](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/getting-started#creating-your-first-kubernetes-resources), I haven't seen this issue come up.
>
> Feel free to browse these working examples of building specific clusters and using them with Kubernetes and Helm providers. Giving the config a skim might give you some ideas for troubleshooting further.

## Howto solve `RBAC` issues

As for the error

```
Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list
```

There is [great explanation by @m-abramovich](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5100#issuecomment-533787541):

> First, some information for newbies.
> In Kubernetes there are:
>
> - Account - something like your ID. Example: john
> - Role - some group in the project permitted to do something. Examples: cluster-admin, it-support, ...
> - Binding - joining Account to Role. "John in it-support" - is a binding.
>
> Thus, in our message above, we see that our Tiller acts as account "default" registered at namespace "kube-system". Most likely you didn't bind him to a sufficient role.
>
> Now back to the problem.
> How do we track it:
>
> - check if you have specific **account** for tiller. Usually it has same name - "tiller":
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] get serviceaccount`
>   create if not:
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] create serviceaccount tiller`
> - check if you have **role** or **clusterrole** (cluster role is "better" for newbies - it is cluster-wide unlike namespace-wide role). If this is not a production, you can use highly privileged role "cluster-admin":
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] get clusterrole`
>   you can check role content via:
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] get clusterrole cluster-admin -o yaml`
> - check if **account** "tiller" in first clause has a binding to **clusterrole** "cluster-admin" that you deem sufficient:
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] get clusterrolebinding`
>   if it is hard to figure out based on names, you can simply create new:
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller`
> - finally, when you have the account, the role and the binding between them, you can check if you really act as this account:
>   `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] get deploy tiller-deploy -o yaml`
>
> I suspect that your output will not have settings "serviceAccount" and "serviceAccountName":
>
> ```
> dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
> restartPolicy: Always
> schedulerName: default-scheduler
> securityContext: {}
> terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
> ```
>
> if yes, than add an account you want tiller to use:
> `kubectl [--namespace kube-system] patch deploy tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'`
> (if you use PowerShell, then check below for post from [@snpdev](https://github.com/snpdev))
> Now you repeat previous check command and see the difference:
>
> ```
> dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
> restartPolicy: Always
> schedulerName: default-scheduler
> securityContext: {}
> serviceAccount: tiller                     <-- new line
> serviceAccountName: tiller          <-- new line
> terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
> ```

## Resources:

- [Using RBAC Authorization | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)
- [Demystifying RBAC in Kubernetes | Cloud Native Computing Foundation](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2018/08/01/demystifying-rbac-in-kubernetes/)
- [Helm | Role-based Access Control](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/rbac/)
- [Lock and Upgrade Provider Versions | Terraform - HashiCorp Learn](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-versioning)

Comment: Thank you so much for your super indepth answer. I have done some more digging and it seems that the aws-auth config map isn't being created, even though it should be and gitlab has permission. This happens because for some reason, Terraform tries to put the configmap in a cluster on localhost, instead of the EKS cluster. Since Terraform runs inside a pod, the cluster it runs in replies with an authentication issue. This appears to be an issue related to the fact I am trying to add two clusters in one Terraform run.